# Saving Spinner Selection to Sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, spinner, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save a spinner's selection to a shared preference, but I'm having trouble getting it to save. I have no problem saving text, but the spinner seems to be a bit more difficult. I'm using a Preference Connector that I found online that seems to work well for text, so that might be part of the problem. Here's a brief section of code that includes only the hair color selector spinner. I think my problem arises when I try to read the SP (readPerson()), but I'm not entirely sure. If you have any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

```
    public class PreferencesActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner hairSpinner; //hair color selector

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_profile);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
          hairSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hair_spinner);
          ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                  this, R.array.hair_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
          adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          hairSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);   
    }
    public void save(View view) {
        int hairText = hairSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        if (hairText != 100)
            PreferenceConnector.writeInteger(this, PreferenceConnector.HAIR,
                    hairText);
    }
    private void readPerson() {
        hairSpinner.setSelection(getText(PreferenceConnector.readInteger(this,
                PreferenceConnector.HAIR, 0)));
    }
}
```

This is the part that I found online (a section of it):

```
    public class PreferenceConnector{
    public static final String PREF_NAME = "PEOPLE_PREFERENCES";
    public static final int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    public static final String HAIR = "HAIR";

    public static void writeInteger(Context context, String key, int value) {
        getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).commit();

    }

    public static int readInteger(Context context, String key, int defValue) {
        return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, defValue);
    }

    public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();

    }

    public static String readString(Context context, String key, String defValue) {
        return getPreferences(context).getString(key, defValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void readPerson() {
    hairSpinner.setSelection(getText(PreferenceConnector.readInteger(this,
            PreferenceConnector.HAIR, 0)));
}
```

Everything looks fine except for the "getText", what is it doing exactly? I'm guessing setSelection is looking for an int but getText is converting it to a String or something.

Comment: I was just trying things. I think this is a major source of the problem but I'm not sure what it would be. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I had to change it to `hairSpinner.setSelection(PreferenceConnector.readInteger...` I just removed the getText part. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!